# How to display only one category in a custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called 'portcat' and I want to display the results of only one portcat category ('games' - which has an ID of '3') on my page. The below code displays all of the categories and I'm not sure what I need to add to make it display only the 'games' category?

```
<div class="greyblock">
        <h4 class="nomar"><?php echo the_title(); ?></h4>
        <div class="sep"></div>

            <?php echo $firstCat[0]->cat_name; ?>

            <div class="clear"></div>
            <ul class="blogpost_list columns3">

            <?php
            $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'port',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'posts_per_page' => get_theme_option("portfolio_work_count"),
            'cat_name' => 'games'
            );
            $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

            ?>
            <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
            #We have:
            #get_permalink() - Full url to post;
            #get_the_title() - Post title;
            #get_the_content() - Post text;
            #get_post_time('U', true) - unix timestamp

            $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );   


            echo "
            <li>
                    <center><img alt='".get_the_title()."' src='".TIMTHUMBURL."?w=120&h=250&src=".$featured_image[0]."'>
                    <h4>".get_the_title()."</h4></center>";
                    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'portcat');
                    if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {

                    $draught_links = array();

                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        $draught_links[] = $term->name;
                    }

                    $on_draught = join( ", ", $draught_links );
                    }

            echo "
            <p>".get_the_excerpt()."</p>
                <center><a href='".get_permalink()."' class='read'>Read More</a></center>                       
                <br class='clear' />
            </li>
            ";  

             endwhile; ?>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php get_pagination() ?>
    <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;  ?>
```

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($wp_query)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `$args` to

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'port',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => get_theme_option("portfolio_work_count"),
    'category__in ' => 'games'
    );
```